# Swatches in magento

Tags: magento, themes

I am using a custom theme in magento and after adding swatches it is showing dropdown list for colors in the product description page, where as I want to add normal color swatches in the page.

Can anyone help for it.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Comment: even i want to close the question can u tell me how to close it @Enigmativity

Comment: I don't think you can close it. The community has to vote to do so or a moderator can.